# Nestjs Rabbitmq use env Variables with @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq Package

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I try to use the [@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/blob/master/packages/rabbitmq/README.md) to connect to rabbitmq and consume messages. I want to use env variables in the @RabbitSubscribe Method. They were always undefined and searching for a solution I came across this package: [@golevelup/profiguration](https://github.com/golevelup/ts-ecosystem/blob/master/libs/profiguration/README.md).

I tried setting it all up, but dont get it to work:

```
import { createProfiguration } from '@golevelup/profiguration';
import { Channel } from 'amqp-connection-manager';

interface Config {
 exchange: string;
 routingKey: string;
 queue: string;
 queueOptions: {
   durable: boolean;
 };
 allowNonJsonMessages: boolean;
 createQueueIfNotExists: boolean;
 errorHandler: () => {};
}

export const subscribeConfig = createProfiguration<Config>({
  exchange: { default: 'test', env: process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME },
  routingKey: { default: 'test', env: process.env.RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY },
  queue: { default: 'test', env: process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME },
  queueOptions: {
  durable: { default: true },
  },
  allowNonJsonMessages: { default: true },
  createQueueIfNotExists: { default: true },
  errorHandler: (channel: Channel, msg: any, error: Error) => {
    console.log(error);
    channel.reject(msg, false);
  },
});


@RabbitSubscribe({
  exchange: subscribeConfig.get('exchange'),
  routingKey: subscribeConfig.get('routingKey'),
  queue: subscribeConfig.get('queue'),
  queueOptions: {
    durable: true,
  },
  allowNonJsonMessages: true,
  createQueueIfNotExists: true,
  errorHandler: (channel: Channel, msg: any, error: Error) => {
    console.log(error);
    channel.reject(msg, false);
  },
})
public async onQueueConsumption(msg: RequestDto, amqpMsg: ConsumeMessage) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

When I start the app I alway get this error:

```
C:\Source\app\node_modules\convict\src\main.js:679
      throw new Error(output)
            ^
Error: errorHandler:  should be of type Function: value was {}
  at Object.validate (C:\Source\app\node_modules\convict\src\main.js:679:17)
  at exports.createProfiguration (C:\Source\app\libs\profiguration\src\lib\profiguration.ts:162:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Source\app\src\app.serviceConfig.ts:17:51)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Source\app\src\app.service.ts:12:1)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the @golevelup/profiguration package.

To use ENV Variables in the @RabbitSubscribe decorator you have to create a factory function that returns a RabbitMQ decorator. There you initialize your ENV values and afterwards set the constants in the RabbitSubscribe Config and return this config.

In the AppService you can then use the factory function to generate the RabbitMQ decorator in your service!

If someone needs the env config im using: [ENV Config](https://blog.devgenius.io/environment-variables-in-nest-js-b989bb0370bf)

And here is the Code:

```
import { Nack, RabbitSubscribe } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
import { Channel } from 'amqp-connection-manager';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { getEnvPath } from './common/helper/env.helper';

const envFilePath: string = getEnvPath(`${__dirname}/common/envs`);


export function getRabbitMQDecorator(): ReturnType<typeof RabbitSubscribe> {
  dotenv.config({path:envFilePath});

  const exchange = process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME;
  const routingKey = process.env.RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY;
  const queue = process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME;

  console.log('Exchange:', exchange);
  console.log('Routing Key:', routingKey);
  console.log('Queue:', queue);

  return RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange,
    routingKey,
    queue,
    queueOptions: {
    durable: true,
  },
  allowNonJsonMessages: true,
  createQueueIfNotExists: true,
  errorHandler: (channel: Channel, msg: any, error: Error) => {
    console.log(error);
    channel.reject(msg, false);
  },
});
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Message} from './app.dto';
import { getRabbitMQDecorator } from './rabbitmq.decorator';

const RabbitMQSubscribe = getRabbitMQDecorator();

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

   @RabbitMQSubscribe
   public async onQueueConsumption(msg: Message, amqpMsg: ConsumeMessage) {
     console.log(msg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple answer.
First step you should create config file with option to RabbitMQ.
For example:

```
    export default registerAs(
  'sfap-rabbitmq',
  () =>
    ({
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: get('SFAP_EXCH').required().asString(),
          type: 'topic', // Change this if needed
          options: {
            durable: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      handlers: {
        handleMessage: {
          exchange: get('SFAP_EXCH').required().asString(),
          routingKey: get('SFAP_ROUTING_KEY').required().asString(),
          queue: get('SFAP_QUEUE').required().asString(),
        },
        handleMessageLog: {
          exchange: get('SFAP_LOG_EXCH').required().asString(),
          routingKey: get('SFAP_LOG_ROUTING_KEY').required().asString(),
          queue: get('SFAP_LOG_QUEUE').required().asString(),
        },
        handleMessageException: {
          exchange: get('SFAP_EXCEPTION_EXCH').required().asString(),
          routingKey: get('SFAP_EXCEPTION_ROUTING_KEY').required().asString(),
          queue: get('SFAP_EXCEPTION_QUEUE').required().asString(),
        },
      },
      uri: get('SFAP_URI').required().asString(),
    } as RabbitMQConfig),
);
```

Where

> handleMessage

is the name method in your class.
Next step you should import your config in module.
Example:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    LoggerModule,
    RabbitMQModule.forRootAsync(RabbitMQModule, {
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('sfap-rabbitmq'),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [urlSend], // Загрузите ваш конфигурационный файл
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RabbitSfap],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [RabbitSfap],
})
export class SfapModule {}
```

And the last part is used.

```
@RabbitSubscribe({
    name: 'handleMessage',
  })
  async handleMessage(data: SfapRabbitDto): Promise<void> {
    ....Functional
  }
```